# Resizing Chartarea and add scrollbar on Chart(not Chartarea)

Tags: c#, charts

I am a semiconductor test engineer.
As semiconductor tech grows high, the test data size grows high too.
Because of data size, excel and spotfire is not a good way to analyze anymore.
So, I decided to use C# to solve it. Yes. I am novice.

Here is my problem.

1. I need to see hundreds chart at once.
   I found a way to add chartareas to chart. However the chartarea size is too small to see.
   I want organize chartareas in three column at fixed size.
2. I found many ways to add scroll bars to chartareas. But there none to add scroll bars to chart.
   There are hundreds chart need to be displayed. So I need scrollbars on chart.

My first language is not a English. If you feel uncomfortable to read my question, I am sorry.
Have a good day.

Comment: I don't think MSChart supports scrollbars for the control. You can workaround by making it large enough an placing it inside a Panel with AutoScroll = true. To place the Chartareas you need to calculate their Positions, which are Elemenzpositions, which are in percent of the container, ie of the chart itself.. - That being said, I don't know how well MChart will hadle hundreds of chartareas..

Comment: Init like so: `int rows = ..
  int cols = ..
  chart.ChartAreas.Clear();
  float pw = 100f / cols.Value;
  float ph = 100f / rows.Value;
  for (int i = 0; i < rows,  i++)
  {
     for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
     {
        ChartArea ca = new ChartArea("CA" + i.+ "-" + j);
        ca.Position = new ElementPosition(j * pw, i * ph, pw , ph );
        chart.ChartAreas.Add(ca);
            Series s = ca.Name.Replace("CA", "S");
        s.ChartType = ..
        s.ChartArea = ca.Name;
        chart.Series.Add(s);
      }
   }`

Comment: Add data like so: `private void cb_iData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var ca in chart.ChartAreas)
    {
        string sn = ca.Name.Replace("CA", "S");
        for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
        {
            chart.Series[sn].Points.AddXY(i * 4, rnd.NextDouble() * i);
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it.

Comment: The numbers and other details (including maybe the InnerPlotPosition, which is also in % referring to the chartarea size, so it could be something like `ca.InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition(10, 5, 90, 85);` ) will need some tweaking.

Comment: I love you. It works perfectly in the way I wanted. How can I thumb up to you?

Comment: Glad to help, no further action necessary, my friend..